# Is it possible to force a lower PHP version in Google's Compute Engine in GCP?

Tags: php, google-cloud-platform, joomla, google-compute-engine

I am working on migrating a Joomla website over to GCP. Everything is migrated to GCP, however, the original site is working under a lower **PHP version 5.7** (I forced it running at this low version PHP through `.htaccess`). I see the PHP version on GCP (Bitnami Joomla) is 7.3.12.

I tried to do the PHP lower version through `.htaccess` in GCP.

I created the `.htaccess` in Joomla location `/opt/bitnami/apps/joomla/htdocs`

The `.htaccess` is as below:

When I opened the site, I received a theme related error, if I go to administrator, I received the following error:

[image]

Clicking on the `Return to Control Panel` doesn't change the error.

I will reach out to the theme vendor and Joomla community and see if there is a way to bypass the theme error and log into the admin to do some upgrades, but if you know there is a way in GCP to force running a lower (or specify) PHP version, it would really help the troubleshooting.

Thank you very much in advance.

Comment: I'm not a sysadmin and I can't anwser you clearly on this, but it's your VM, you do what you want on it!! Install manually the version of PHP that you want. But remember, you are responsible of the system security. If you install a buggy version, and you are attacked, Google can't nothing for you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks for everyone's suggestions, I decided I should really upgrade my Joomla site, maybe rebuild it, and then migrate it to GCP - this would be a lengthy process, and definitely would incur some cost due to the theme I used was a commercial theme from Rocket.

Answer (score 0):

There is nothing related with `.htaccess` and the php version. Compute engine is IAS (Infrastructure as Platform) which means you can install whatever version you need.

Just login to your machine(VM) and install a particular version of PHP (in your case 5.7) and deploy your Joomla website to the Compute Engine.